# How to stop reloading of a page if i'm using Tapestry?

Tags: html, tapestry

I'm using ITreeModel of Tapestry4.2,whenever i click on ITreeModel tree structure it refreshes/reloads a page which in turn results in resetting all other fields in html page to blank.I want to avoid this reloading of page so any one help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ajax or saving page data in session, can not say how this will be in t4 though

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of use case that prompted the creation of Tapestry 5. In your situation, you will probably want to locate an existing Ajax tree widget and find a way to provide it with data. Without significant more details and time, that's about as far as anyone can help you.

Comment: Locate an existing Ajax tree widget and find a way to provide it with data?I din't get you?

Comment: Tapestry 4 doesn't have the facilities you need; however you should be able to find an existing JavaScript tree widget out there (that's what Google's for), and then it becomes a different problem: integrating Tapestry with that JavaScript. That's a much easier problem in Tapestry 5 than Tapestry 4.